# CUDA signal to host

Tags: c++, cuda

Is there a way to signal (success/failure) to the host at the end of kernel execution?

I am looking at an iterative process where calculations are made in device and after each iteration, a boolean variable is passed to host that tells if the process has converged. Based on the variable, host decides to either stop iterating or go through another round of iteration.

Copying a single boolean variable at the end of every iteration nullifies the time gain obtained through parallelization. Hence, I would like to find a way to let the host know of the convergence status (success/failure) without having to CudaMemCpy every time. 
Note: The time issue exists after using pinned memory to transfer data.

Alternatives that I have looked at.

1. **asm("trap;"); & assert();**
   These will trigger respectively Unknown error and cudaErrorAssert in host. Unfortunately, they are "sticky" in that the error cannot be reset using CudaGetLastError. The only way is to reset device using cudaDeviceReset().
2. **using CudaHostAllocMapped to avoid CudaMemCpy** This is of no use as it does not offer any time based advantage over standard pinned memory allocation + CudaMemCpy. (Pg 460, MultiCore and GPU Programming, An Integrated Approach, Morgran Kruffmann 2014).

Will appreciate other ways to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the real issue here is that your iteration kernel run time is very short (on the order of 100us or less), meaning the work per iteration is very small.  The best solution might be to try to increase the work per iteration (refactor your code/algorithm, tackle a larger problem, etc.)

However, here are some possibilities:

1. Use mapped/pinned memory.  Your claim in item 2 of your question is unsupported, IMO, without a lot more context than a page reference to a book that many of us probably don't have available to look at.
2. Use dynamic parallelism.  Move your kernel launch process to a CUDA parent kernel that is issuing child kernels.  Whatever boolean is set by the child kernel will be immediately discoverable in the parent kernel, without any need for a cudaMemcpy operation or mapped/pinned memory.
3. Use a pipelined algorithm, and overlap a speculative kernel launch with the device->host copy of the boolean, for each pipeline stage.

I consider the first two items above fairly obvious, so I'll provide a worked example for item 3.  The basic idea is that we will ping-pong between two streams, launching the kernel alternately into one stream then the other.  We will have a 3rd stream so that we can overlap the device->host copy operations with the execution of the next launch.  Due to the overlap of D->H copy with kernel execution, there is effectively no "cost" for the copy operation, it is hidden by kernel execution work.

Here's a fully worked example, plus a nvvp timeline:

```
$ cat t267.cu
#include <stdio.h>


const int stop_count = 5;
const long long tdelay = 1000000LL;

__global__ void test_kernel(int *icounter, bool *istop, int *ocounter, bool *ostop){

  if (*istop) return;
  long long start = clock64();
  while (clock64() < tdelay+start);
  int my_count = *icounter;
  my_count++;
  if (my_count >= stop_count) *ostop = true;
  *ocounter = my_count;
}

int main(){
  volatile bool *v_stop;
  volatile int *v_counter;
  bool *h_stop, *d_stop1, *d_stop2, *d_s1, *d_s2, *d_ss;
  int *h_counter, *d_counter1, *d_counter2, *d_c1, *d_c2, *d_cs;
  cudaStream_t s1, s2, s3, *sp1, *sp2, *sps;
  cudaEvent_t e1, e2, *ep1, *ep2, *eps;
  cudaStreamCreate(&s1);
  cudaStreamCreate(&s2);
  cudaStreamCreate(&s3);
  cudaEventCreate(&e1);
  cudaEventCreate(&e2);
  cudaMalloc(&d_counter1, sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_stop1, sizeof(bool));
  cudaMalloc(&d_counter2, sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_stop2, sizeof(bool));
  cudaHostAlloc(&h_stop, sizeof(bool), cudaHostAllocDefault);
  cudaHostAlloc(&h_counter, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocDefault);
  v_stop = h_stop;
  v_counter = h_counter;
  int n_counter = 1;
  h_stop[0] = false;
  h_counter[0] = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_stop1, h_stop, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_stop2, h_stop, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_counter1, h_counter, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_counter2, h_counter, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  sp1 = &s1;
  sp2 = &s2;
  ep1 = &e1;
  ep2 = &e2;
  d_c1 = d_counter1;
  d_c2 = d_counter2;
  d_s1 = d_stop1;
  d_s2 = d_stop2;
  test_kernel<<<1,1, 0, *sp1>>>(d_c1, d_s1, d_c2, d_s2);
  cudaEventRecord(*ep1, *sp1);
  cudaStreamWaitEvent(s3, *ep1, 0);
  cudaMemcpyAsync(h_stop, d_s2, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s3);
  cudaMemcpyAsync(h_counter, d_c2, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s3);
  while (v_stop[0] == false){
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(*sp2, *ep1, 0);
    sps = sp1; // ping-pong
    sp1 = sp2;
    sp2 = sps;
    eps = ep1;
    ep1 = ep2;
    ep2 = eps;
    d_cs = d_c1;
    d_c1 = d_c2;
    d_c2 = d_cs;
    d_ss = d_s1;
    d_s1 = d_s2;
    d_s2 = d_ss;
    test_kernel<<<1,1, 0, *sp1>>>(d_c1, d_s1, d_c2, d_s2);
    cudaEventRecord(*ep1, *sp1);
    while (n_counter > v_counter[0]);
    n_counter++;
    if(v_stop[0]  == false){
      cudaStreamWaitEvent(s3, *ep1, 0);
      cudaMemcpyAsync(h_stop, d_s2, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s3);
      cudaMemcpyAsync(h_counter, d_c2, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s3);
    }
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();  // optional
  printf("terminated at counter = %d\n", v_counter[0]);
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t267 t267.cu
$ ./t267
terminated at counter = 5
$
```

[image: nvvp profiler timeline]

In the above diagram, we see that 5 kernel launches are evident (actually 6) andy they are bouncing back and forth between two streams. (The 6th kernel launch, which we would expect from the code organization and pipelining, is a very short line at the end of stream15 above.  This kernel launches but immediately witness that `stop` is true, so it exits.) The device -> host copies are in a 3rd stream.  If we zoom in closely at the handoff from one kernel iteration to the next:

[image: nvvp zoomed]

we see that even these very short D->H memcpy operations are essentially overlapped with the next kernel execution.  For reference, the gap between kernel executions above is about 5us.

Note that this was entirely done on linux.  If you attempt this on windows WDDM, it may be difficult to achieve anything similar, due to WDDM command batching.  Windows TCC should approximately duplicate linux behavior, however.